SymmetricDS encrypted password in engine file in Docker or Kubernetes environment
I am running a SymmetricDS server in Kubernetes environment as pod. I want to use encrypted password in the engine files. Following below link for the same:
https://symmetricds.sourceforge.net/doc/3.12/html/user-guide.html#_encrypted_passwords
It is fine to create the encrypted password, however the problem is encrypted value changes every time a new pod is created.
Could someone help me with keeping the encrypted password same across pods.

Here are three options you can choose between:

Persist SymmetricDS's security directory, specifically the keystore file. Then the encryption key will be available after a restart.
Customize a dockerfile to provide a custom keystore. This will work because the keystore will be packaged within the image.
Comment out the sym.keystore.file property from SymmetricDS's conf/sym_service.conf file. This will work because SymmetricDS will generate an encryption key based on the static keystore password.


Thanks Evan for the help. I have a option 2 setup running, I am replacing the keystore file while creating the image. However, it still does not work.    Option 1 will become expensive for me, hence not trying. Cannot use option 3, as I have a option 2 setup. Anything you can suggest with option 2 setup.

The default keystore for SymmetricDS is empty (no keys). You can run a command like follows:
symadmin encrypt-text sometext
That will populate the keystore with a secret key. Then you can use this keystore to copy into new images, where the secret key will then be able to be used for decrypting successfully previously encrypted values.
